# How to traverse dom tree from a list of elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-traversal

I have HTML snippet which looks like this. I generate this snippet multiple times form the backend. When I click the Save button, I catch which Save button was clicked using $(this) selector. Now I want to grab the attribute item-id of the corresponding Save button. I have the following jquery code snippet. But it does not work. I have tried to look but I don't know where the error is.

```
<td><input type="text" size="10" value="val1" item-id="id1"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="val2" size="4"></td> 
<td>
  <button class="btn btn-primary save-btn">Save</i></button>
</td>
```

Here is the jquery snippet

```
 $(".save-btn").click(function(){
        var ems = $(this).parent().siblings();
       var item_id = ems[0].child().attr("item-id");
   }
```

Comment: So is there a JS error being thrown somewhere, or is it just not doing what you expect?

Comment: yes, it thorws an error: "Uncaught TypeError: ems[0].child is not a function"

Comment: @PHPglue , Yes I know. But we are allowed to use any custom attributes. It does not have to be HTML defined. It is not the problem at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`click` doesn't work on dynamically added elements.You need to use `on('click')`. Also there is no method `.child()` so you need to use `.children().first()`.

This is the corrected code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.save-btn', function(){
   var ems = $(this).parent().siblings();
   var item_id = ems.children().first().attr("item-id");
});
```

```js
// The text
var text="";
text += "<td><input type=\"text\" size=\"10\" value=\"val1\" item-id=\"id1\"><\/td>";
text += "<td><input type=\"text\" value=\"val2\" size=\"4\"><\/td> ";
text += "<td>";
text += "  <button class=\"btn btn-primary save-btn\">Save<\/i><\/button>";
text += "<\/td>";


// Adding the text to html
$('body').html(text);


$(document).on('click', '.save-btn', function(){
    var ems = $(this).parent().siblings();
    console.log(ems);
    var item_id = ems.children().first().attr("item-id");
    alert(item_id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Surprisingly it works. But how is it possible ? ems is not a single element as you can see, instead it is list ( or sth like that) of elements instead.And children of a list of elements does not make any sense. But the code works.

Comment: children() ends up getting all the children of every ems i.e. all the inputs and we take the first input. You can also do `ems.first().children().first()` or `ems.eq(0)` as the other answer mentions

Answer (score 2):

better replace item-id="id1" to data attribute html5 data-id="id1" then replace code attr('item-id') to data('id')...

```js
$(document).on('click','.save-btn', function(){
        var ems = $(this).parent().siblings(),
            item_id = ems.eq(0).children('input').attr("item-id");
             alert(item_id);
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
<td><input type="text" size="10" value="val1" item-id="id1"></td>
<td><input type="text" value="val2" size="4"></td> 
<td>
  <button class="btn btn-primary save-btn"><i>Save</i></button>
</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: ems its array of td, eq(index) function return element from array with index